# Как исправить ошибку fatal error _mingw.h no such file or directory?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

> fatal error _mingw.h no such file or directory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This is a native C program.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Проверить установлены ли devel пакеты. Если все криво или удалено случайно ручками, проще переустановить.

Comment: @NewView файл _mingw.h установлен в текущую папку.

Comment: Так вероятно он его ищет по другому пути, явно ваша папка не является корнем, добавьте ключ `-I ./` к строке компиляции (GCC). И если у вас он не находиться, разумнее переустановить.